# Why is pyserial padding USB Packets?

Tags: linux, usb, pyserial

I'm trying to connect a Newport AGILIS AG-UC8 controller to my Linux via USB.
Internally, this controller has an FT232R usb-to-serial chip, that should accept simple text commands, such as "VE\r\n" to print the version.

This works fine when using the provided windows driver and software, but on Linux (tested with pyserial and others), the chip doesn't answer. Basically I initialized the device with the values that the Windows device manager showed and then just sent the command.

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
ser.write("VE\r\n")
```

I did some debugging with wireshark USB captures:

Windows packet (working, from the provided software):

```
0000   1b 00 20 9a 40 55 8a ad ff ff 00 00 00 00 09 00   .. .@U..........
0010   00 01 00 03 00 02 03 04 00 00 00 56 45 0d 0a      ...........VE..
```

[image: windows packet screenshot]

Linux packet (not working, from pyserial):

```
0000   80 dd 35 82 e5 99 ff ff 53 03 02 08 02 00 2d 00   ..5.....S.....-.
0010   b6 08 41 60 00 00 00 00 3a 6f 00 00 8d ff ff ff   ..A`....:o......
0020   04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0040   56 45 0d 0a                                       VE..
```

[image: linux packet screenshot]

As you can see, the packet on windows is much smaller, and does not contain the padding zeros. These zeros follow immediately after the data-length field (04), so I am wondering whether they pose the problem to the controller.

Is there a way to send the data without zero padding? Preferably in pyserial, but for now I'd be happy with any solution that lets me speak to my device.

Comment: Try writing "VE" without "\r\n", it might be causing the lack of response.   If I was a speaking controller language, I won't be expecting those, unless I specifically asked for them in the documentation.  It's a waste of two bytes.

Comment: @vhoang the windows packet ends on 56 45 0d 0a which are the \r\n and I think the controller expects them

Comment: I see, I found the doc and it does list term character as CR/LF.   The only other thing I noticed there that might cause some issue is that the baud rate is expected to be 921600.   You shouldn't be able to read a proper response at 9600 which is odd if it worked in windows.

Comment: Maybe I should still try the 921600 baud rate, but the manual for my product actually specified 9600...

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, but not necessarily solving your problem: those extra zeros are due to the sniffer capturing traffic between the kernel and libusb.   It is also the reason why your capture looks different between environments.

Specifically they are the values stuffed into the pcap_usb_setup structure that sits after urb and data length.   There's no particular way or reason to try to eliminate them.

```
/*
 * Header prepended by linux kernel to each event.
 * Appears at the front of each packet in DLT_USB_LINUX captures.
 */
typedef struct _usb_header {
    uint64_t id;
    uint8_t event_type;
    uint8_t transfer_type;
    uint8_t endpoint_number;
    uint8_t device_address;
    uint16_t bus_id;
    char setup_flag;/*if !=0 the urb setup header is not present*/
    char data_flag; /*if !=0 no urb data is present*/
    int64_t ts_sec;
    int32_t ts_usec;
    int32_t status;
    uint32_t urb_len;
    uint32_t data_len; /* amount of urb data really present in this event*/
    pcap_usb_setup setup;
} pcap_usb_header;
```

```
/*
 * USB setup header as defined in USB specification.
 * Appears at the front of each Control S-type packet in DLT_USB captures.
 */
typedef struct _usb_setup {
    uint8_t bmRequestType;
    uint8_t bRequest;
    uint16_t wValue;
    uint16_t wIndex;
    uint16_t wLength;
} pcap_usb_setup;
```